# How to use UIPinchGestureRecognizer velocity

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`'s property `velocity` to play an animation in a SceneKit node when the user stops pinching, but I don't understand how the `velocity` property is calculated/should be used.

Here is my code:

```
var initialScale = simd_float3(1)
@objc private func handlePinch(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
let scale = simd_float3(Float(sender.scale))
let state = sender.state
let vel = Float(sender.velocity)

if state == .began {
  updateQ.async(group: updateGrp) {
    log.debug("Begin scale: \(scale)")
    log.debug("Begin vel: \(vel)")

    if let node = self.activeNode {
      self.initialScale = node.simdScale
    }
    else {
      self.initialScale = self.layeredImgNode.simdScale
    }
  }
}
else if state == .changed {
  updateQ.async(group: updateGrp) {
    log.debug("Changed scale: \(scale)")
    log.debug("Changed vel: \(vel)")

    let scale = self.initialScale * scale

    if let node = self.activeNode {
      node.simdScale = scale
    }
    else {
      self.layeredImgNode.simdScale = scale
    }
  }
}
else if state == .ended {
  updateQ.async(group: updateGrp) {
    log.debug("End scale: \(scale)")
    log.debug("End vel: \(vel)")


    // Calculate for how long to run the animation
    let time = Double(vel / Float(10))
    let target = self.initialScale * (scale + simd_float3(vel))
    log.debug("End target: \(target) and time: \(time)")

    self.initialScale = simd_float3(1)

    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = time
    if let node = self.activeNode {
      node.simdScale = target
    }
    else {
      self.layeredImgNode.simdScale = target
    }
    SCNTransaction.commit()
  }
}
```

The documentation states that `velocity` is "The velocity of the pinch in scale factor per second". However, I still don't understand how I should use it. Could someone help me?

Thanks.